# Ajax filter to display only the list starting with input pattern/letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Am writing code to display the list of email matching with input given by users, for example if i type 'a' as input its displaying all email list containing 'a' anywhere in it, instead i want only the list of email starting with 'a', please help me on this, Here i have written some code where it searches the list based on  mentioned in my  code, pardon me if i went wrong somewhere, thank you.

**input.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form" name ="form" method = "POST" action="invite_alpha_email_gst1.php" class="wizard-big" autocomplete = "off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="input-group">
<input id="filter" type="text" name="alpha_mail" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here..." style="width: 500px; height: 30px;"></div>
<input type="hidden" class="mail" name="mail_body">
<button type="submit" name="invite_upload_alpha_mail" id = "submit" style="width: 500px; height: 30px;"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Send to filtered emails" class="btn btn-info">Send to all filtered ids</button>
</form>
//ajax call
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        (function ($) {

            $('#filter').keyup(function () {

                var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
                $('.searchable tr').hide();
                $('.searchable tr').filter(function () {
                    return rex.test($(this).text());
                }).show();

            })

        }(jQuery));

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM email_contacts WHERE vault_no = '"   $_SESSION['vault_no'] . "' ORDER BY email ");
```

change your query to above